# Difference between vector and equation of vector

Tags: vector-analysis

What is the difference between a vector $pq$ and an equation of vector $pq$?

Comment: please provide more details.  what do you mean by "equation of vector pq"?

Comment: What does $pq$ mean?

Answer (score 4):

A vector is an element of a vector space. A vector equation, which is what you might mean, is simply an equation involving vectors. For instance, the vector equation $r=a+\lambda b$ with $\lambda\in R$ describes a line.